# Best way to handle errors in Grails domain class validation

Tags: grails, groovy, error-handling

We have an API command like "student/create" to create a new student object. The code looks like this:

```
def student = new Student(firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, email: email)

if (! student.validate()) {
    response.error = "UNKNOWN_ERROR" // in case we can't find anything better

    student.errors.allErrors.each { error ->
        // set response.error to an appropriate value
        println error
    }
} else {
    student.save()
}
```

Our goal is to give a reasonable error message like "EMAIL_DUPLICATE" or "FIRSTNAME_LENGTH" on a validation fail, so we want to test the errors we get against a set of expected errors so we can respond like that.

Here's what we get from that `println`:

```
Field error in object 'com.example.Student' on field 'email': rejected value [student@example.com]; codes [com.example.Student.email.unique.error.com.example.Student.email,com.example.Student.email.unique.error.email,com.example.Student.email.unique.error.java.lang.String,com.example.Student.email.unique.error,student.email.unique.error.com.example.Student.email,student.email.unique.error.email,student.email.unique.error.java.lang.String,student.email.unique.error,com.example.Student.email.unique.com.example.Student.email,com.example.Student.email.unique.email,com.example.Student.email.unique.java.lang.String,com.example.Student.email.unique,student.email.unique.com.example.Student.email,student.email.unique.email,student.email.unique.java.lang.String,student.email.unique,unique.com.example.Student.email,unique.email,unique.java.lang.String,unique]; arguments [email,class com.example.Student,student@example.com.org]; default message [Property [{0}] of class [{1}] with value [{2}] must be unique]
```

How can I figure out that this means the email is already used in the database so that I can tell the API user that?

(to be clear, I want to give a computer-readable message like "EMAIL_DUPLICATE" instead of something like "Property email of class Student with value student@example.com must be unique")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure it would work in more situations than just this one, but does:

```
    println "${error.objectName}_${error.codes[-1]}".toUpperCase()
```

Get you anywhere near?

Comment: I changed `error.objectName` to `error.field`, which works great as far as I can tell. Gets us `EMAIL_UNIQUE`, `FIRSTNAME_SIZE.TOOSMALL`, `LASTNAME_BLANK`, etc. Exactly the kind of messages we want! Thanks!